# Why cifar10 benchmark shows slow performance on every n x 100 step?

Tags: tensorflow

I have tried to get performance comparison result between source built and google provided .whl files for tensorflow-gpu runs. I have tried more than tens of bench mark tests, and I always get slow performance on every n x 100  step like 0, 100, 200, .... I cannot figure out the reason. Who, one of you, expert of tensorflow, can answer for me?

I am running ubuntu(18.04). fedora(27, 28), Windows, and CUDA 9.0/9.1/9.2
I've tested with tf1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9.
My GPU is 1080ti/11GB.
My cpu is intel 4690k with 32G dram.

attached one sample

[image].

Tnank you very much in advance.

Dae-Chul Jo
dcjo00@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

It could be for some different reasons:

1. Every 100 steps you are saving the model
2. Every 100 steps you are testing validation data
3. Every 100 steps you are saving logs to tensorboard

These are my first guesses in order of probability, if you provide code I could study it more deeply.

Hope it helps! :)

EDIT: it ended up being:

`tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession` has a default of saving summaries every 100 steps. Which was proposal 3.

Comment: Thank you very much on your prompt answer. I am using the same cifar10_train.py from google's tutorial in the directory "tensorflow/models/tutorilas/image/cifa10" .

Comment: There you go mate, summaries are saved every 100 steps!

Comment: I've found that cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py includes such summaries, but I am using cifar10_train.py, not cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py.

Comment: I've found that cifar10_train.py uses tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession whose save_summaries_steps's default settting is 100, so that I should set this None, I think. Thank you for your answers. It provided very good clue.

Comment: Added it to my answer. I am glad I helped.